# Cant seem to see content of inkscape file

Tags: inkscape

I worked on some design on inkscape and something weird happened. I can no longer see the contents for file when i open inkscape. All I see I blank whitespace, I don't even see the black rectangular borders I used to see before. When I look at the svg file in finder I can see the contents in the file thumbnail but once i open in inkscape I dont see anything. I tried fitting the page to the content and changing width and height of the document and nothing happened.

I am new to inkscape so this is confusing to me. Anybody have any ideas how to rectify this?

Comment: Without you sharing the file, this is difficult to diagnose. You may try tabbing to select and explore objects, or using View-Display Mode-Outline to see if your objects became transparent somehow.

Comment: @Juancho this is the link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjpCYpimNOZikmM5c7n1NAhvxxkDUPy_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Juancho the file freezes on me when i open it in inkscape

Comment: @user3775998: You can get more details here: https://chat.inkscape.org

Comment: @s.ouchene thanks man. they solved my problem for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your document in Inkscape then press <kbd>5</kbd> to zoom to the page (or using the menu: **View** → **Zoom** → **Zoom Page**).

You should see the drawing:

[image: The drawing after opening it in Inkscape]

Comment: thanks a lot. i can see the contents now but cant seem to select anything. any ideas?

Comment: @user3775998: I can select the objects on that document. BTW which version of Inkscape are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.1.2

Comment: @user3775998: I have tested that on version 1.1.2 and I can select the object and move them around. Try selecting the objects using the menu: **Object** > **Objects**. Select the items from the dialog.

Comment: am using mac os monterrey. what OS are u using?

Comment: @user3775998: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: feel like its something to do with macOS as i have tried it on 2 macs and the same thing happens